# Reskit For Empty Parent

Tags: core-data, restkit-0.20

The response i have is

```
<people>
  <person>
    ...
  </person>
  <person>
    ...
  </person>
</people>
```

I want to do mapping of person with my coredata object contact. Issue is when there is no person records fetched the response has empty people tags  and it gives me exception of no mappable objects found.

My mapping is as:

```
+ (RKEntityMapping *)contactMapping {

    //RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Contact class]];
    RKEntityMapping *mapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Contact"
                                               inManagedObjectStore:[[HRCoreData sharedInstance] objectStore]];

    NSDictionary *mappingDictionary = @{@"id.text": @"contactId",
                                    @"title.text": @"title",
                                    @"first-name.text": @"firstName",
                                    @"last-name.text": @"lastName",
                                    @"company-name.text": @"companyName"
                                    };

    [mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:mappingDictionary];
    mapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"contactId"];
    return mapping;


}
```

Response descriptor setup is:

```
RKResponseDescriptor *personResponseDescriptors = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:[MappingProvider contactMapping] method:RKRequestMethodGET pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"people.person" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
[self addResponseDescriptor:personResponseDescriptors];
```

How to check if child exists or if parent is empty and do mapping accordingly?

@EDIT- I tried dynamic mapping this way:

```
+ (RKDynamicMapping *) dynPeopleMapping {
    // Basic setup
    RKDynamicMapping* dynamicMapping = [RKDynamicMapping new];

    RKEntityMapping *conMapping = [MappingProvider contactMapping];
    [conMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"person" toKeyPath:@"Contact" withMapping:dynamicMapping]];

    // Configure the dynamic mapping via a block    
    [dynamicMapping setObjectMappingForRepresentationBlock:^RKEntityMapping *(id representation) {
         if([representation valueForKeyPath:@"people.person"]){
             // what can i do here to map person with contact when it exists?
             return conMapping;
        }else
            return nil;
     }];

     return dynamicMapping;
}
```

But its not mapping person to contact as person is collection of array with data and contact is a core data object for single person. How can i map them?

Comment: You could use a dynamic mapping, or have the server return a different status code when there's no content.

Comment: @Wain thanks for the reply. I have edited my post (no success!)

Comment: Same error? I think you'll need to use just `@"people"` as the key path in the response descriptor, then a dynamic mapping. You may also need a container object. Can you change the interface to JSON? I think it is also an XML specific problem because of the nested key.

Comment: No i cannot change it to json. Server reponse is in xml and i cannot invest time in parsing xml to json for now. If i use people in response descriptor how would be the mapping ( i already tried that and it gives error of person is not mappable to contact)?

Comment: Also the contact is RKEntity object (for coredata) and i don't want to store the people as there is no data for it in response its just the outer tag. Will i need any relationship of both in datamodel?

Comment: You may be able to use a normal object as the container and an entity as you are for the person, with a relationship. I can't say I've tried to do exactly what you have, and with XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved !

Thanks @Wain.
I simply created people nsobject class and person nsmanaged object. The dynamic mapping is as:

```
+ (RKDynamicMapping *) dynPeopleMapping {
    // Basic setup
    RKDynamicMapping* dynamicMapping = [RKDynamicMapping new];
    RKObjectMapping *peopleMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[HRPeople class]];
    RKEntityMapping *personMapping = [MappingProvider contactMapping];

    [dynamicMapping setObjectMappingForRepresentationBlock:^RKObjectMapping *(id representation) {
        NSLog(@"people.person:%@", [[representation valueForKeyPath:@"people.person"] description]);
        if([representation valueForKeyPath:@"person"]){
            return personMapping;
        }else
            return peopleMapping;
    }];
    return dynamicMapping;
}
```

And the response descriptor as:

```
RKResponseDescriptor *personResponseDescriptors = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:[MappingProvider dynPeopleMapping] method:RKRequestMethodGET pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"people" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
[self addResponseDescriptor:personResponseDescriptors];
```